# Angular deployment to production fails for my first app

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi I am a newbie to Angular and have created a simple calculator application that you can see here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ibplpz

The application for the most part works fine.. however when I try and run "ng build --prod" I get allot of ERRORs appearing in the cli:

> ERROR in src/app/calculator/calculator.component.html(6,64): :
>   Argument of type '"allClear"' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'Operator'. src/app/calculator/calculator.component.html(7,64): :
>   Argument of type '"clear"' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'Operator'. src/app/calculator/calculator.component.html(9,67): :
>   Argument of type '"divide"' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'Operator'. src/app/calculator/calculator.component.html(13,67): :
>   Argument of type '"multiply"' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'Operator'. src/app/calculator/calculator.component.html(17,67): :
>   Argument of type '"minus"' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'Operator'. src/app/calculator/calculator.component.html(21,11): :
>   Argument of type '"add"' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'Operator'. src/app/calculator/calculator.component.html(24,38): :
>   Argument of type '"dot"' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'Operator'. src/app/calculator/calculator.component.html(25,11): :
>   Argument of type '"equal"' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'Operator'.

Please advise also I was wondering if the general structure of the application should be restructured to make it better 'Angular' best parctice.

Comment: You have to solve all the error which are listed during build, assign above variable as a operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though `Operator` has all the values in the error you get, it is still not the same type. I updated [your blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xtm8ry?file=src/app/calculator/calculator.component.html)

You should define a class attribute like this

`operators = Operator;`

Within your html, change string parameters to `operators.allClear`, `operators.add` etc.

For example,

Change

`(click)="clickOperator('allClear')"`

to

`(click)="clickOperator(operators.allClear)"`

With this way, angular will not complain about type mismatch. Also, you can easily refactor your code and change enum values.